# How can I ensure uniform spacing for tabular and tabularx with custom tablenotes environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, enumitem, threeparttable

**EDIT** Somewhat more minimal example. I can take out `booktabs` and avoid `\tnote` and still get the issue. I can also change `threeparttablex` back to default `threeparttable`. Taking `threeparttable` out eliminates the problem, though, so I've kept `threeparttable` and `enumitem` in the new version of the example.

---

I use `threeparttable` and `threeparttablex` with a custom `tablenotes` environment for tabulars created using both `tabular` and `tabularx`. One feature of my custom environment is that it sets the notes in `\footnotesize`. Another is that it does not require me to manually number the notes. (That is, the notes are numbered automatically as well as being `referable` in `threeparttablex`'s sense.)

However, I cannot figure out how to get uniform vertical spacing between the `tabular`/`tabularx` and the `tablenotes`.

I'm using `enumitem` to create the custom `tablenotes` environment and I can put `before={\footnotesize}`, say, for the font. If I do this, the spacing seems about right for `tabular`s, but all wrong for `tabularx`s.

If I use `before={\unskip\medskip\footnotesize}` or I change `topsep` to `\medskipamount`, the spacing seems about right for `tabularx`s, but really not right for `tabular`s. More importantly, the additional space is added in *both* cases, so `tabular`s and `tabularx`s still don't look alike in the relevant respect.

Either way, that is, I'm not getting the *uniform* spacing demanded by typographical consistency.

How can I ensure consistency, while keeping the smaller font size? (I also want to keep the automated numbering, but that is not really relevant here as far as I can tell.)

[image: 3 attempts x 2 cases = 6 results]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\textsuperscript{\alph*},ref=\alph*,itemsep=\z@,topsep=\z@skip,partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.2em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\footnotesize}}
\makeatother
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Initial Attempt: Case 1}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xl}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Initial Attempt: Case 2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\makeatletter

\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\textsuperscript{\alph*},ref=\alph*,itemsep=\z@,topsep=\z@skip,partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.2em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\unskip\medskip\footnotesize}}

\makeatother

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Second Attempt: Case 1}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xl}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Second Attempt: Case 2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\makeatletter

\setlist[tablenotes]{%
  label=\textsuperscript{\alph*},%
  ref=\alph*,%
  itemsep=\z@,%
  topsep=\medskipamount,%
  partopsep=\z@skip,%
  parsep=\z@,%
  itemindent=\z@,%
  labelindent=\tabcolsep,%
  labelsep=.2em,%
  leftmargin=*,%
  align=left,%
  before={\footnotesize}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Third Attempt: Case 1}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xl}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Third Attempt: Case 2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[**EDIT** to remove more minimal case added in previous edit, which turns out to be more minimal at the cost of not being an actual case.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It's the `tabular` width measurement code in `threeparttable` what did it. (`tabular*` and `tabularx` have an explicit width so `threeparttable` just uses the specified width and doesn't measure anything in those cases.)

The following change eliminates the change by preserving the value of `\prevdepth` so the baseline calculation for the following text (the notes in your example) is unaffected.

The existing code was explicitly setting the `\prevdepth` to 0pt so was clearly intentional, but undocumented. I've changed it here but the `threeparttable` author is more often right than wrong about TeX box manipulations, so perhaps I'm missing something. However....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\makeatletter

\def\TPT@measurement{%
 \ifdim\wd\@tempboxb<\TPTminimum
  \hsize \TPTminimum
 \else
  \hsize\wd\@tempboxb
 \fi
 \xdef\TPT@hsize{\hsize\the\hsize \noexpand\@parboxrestore}\TPT@hsize
 \ifx\TPT@docapt\@undefined\else
  \TPT@docapt \vskip.2\baselineskip
 \fi \par 
\dimen@\dp\@tempboxb % new
\box\@tempboxb
 \ifvmode \prevdepth\dimen@ \fi% was \z@ not \dimen@
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\textsuperscript{\alph*},ref=\alph*,itemsep=\z@,topsep=\z@skip,partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.2em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\footnotesize}}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Initial Attempt: Case 1}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xl}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Initial Attempt: Case 2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\makeatletter

\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\textsuperscript{\alph*},ref=\alph*,itemsep=\z@,topsep=\z@skip,partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.2em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\unskip\medskip\footnotesize}}

\makeatother

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Second Attempt: Case 1}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xl}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Second Attempt: Case 2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\makeatletter

\setlist[tablenotes]{%
  label=\textsuperscript{\alph*},%
  ref=\alph*,%
  itemsep=\z@,%
  topsep=\medskipamount,%
  partopsep=\z@skip,%
  parsep=\z@,%
  itemindent=\z@,%
  labelindent=\tabcolsep,%
  labelsep=.2em,%
  leftmargin=*,%
  align=left,%
  before={\footnotesize}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Third Attempt: Case 1}
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xl}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Third Attempt: Case 2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \hline
      here is some test & and some more stuff here\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item Yertle the turtle was King of the Pond \dots.
      \item I'm OK.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit confused by the explanation. Why does not measuring the width mean the depth is set to zero? Is it not explicitly zeroed if the width is measured? I don't quite understand the connection. (But I've been arguing with Ti*k*Z and `standalone`, so I don't quite understand anything right now.)

Comment: @cfr to answer "Why?" But you have the cases backwards, tabular variants with a width argument are not changed by threeeparttable and have their natural width, but the basic `tabular` is changed, to measure its natural width but the original package code then sets  \prevdepth to 0 just in that case for reasons that are not clear. you would have to ask Donald, I might mail him and do exactly that, the code branch that measures the width of a `tabular` in `threeparttable` just ends with `\prevdepth=0pt` and my change here stops it doing that.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see. I thought you were saying something more causal. Thanks again, I'm going to try out adding this to my `.sty` ... ;).

Comment: Finally, the tick works again!